# Dropbox for Swift: Upload a csv file to Dropbox using SwiftyDropbox(cocoapods) not working

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox, swiftydropbox

I created a small app that creates a CSV file and now I want to upload it to a dropbox folder.

[Problem Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPqCU.png)

```
import SwiftyDropbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    func myButtonInControllerPressed() {
        DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromController(UIApplication.shared,
                                                      controller: self,
                                                      openURL: { (url: URL) -> Void in
                                                        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        })
    }

let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient
        let fileData = "teste.csv".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

        client?.files.upload(path: "/test/path/in/Dropbox/account/HealthkitFromTheGround", input: fileData)
            .response { response, error in
                if let response = response {
                    print(response)
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            .progress { progressData in
                print(progressData)
        }

let fileName = "teste.csv"
                let tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory()
                let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempDir, isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

do {
                            try csvString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
                            print("Created file")
                        } catch {
                            print("Failed to create file: \(error)")
                            return
                        }
```

What should I do to write directly to the app dropbox folder?

Thanks!

Comment: The following line doesn't look correct.  let fileData = "teste.csv".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

Comment: 1. The file path is wrong.  2.  Why are you creating a Data object?

Comment: The `upload` method is the right way to upload to Dropbox. You seem to just be passing in the data for a sample string (`"teste.csv"`) though. You should pass in the data for the file you want to upload instead.

Comment: Hi Greg. I'm just trying to follow 'Upload-style request' from the official Dropbox Swift SDK [https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox#upload-style-request] ... but I must be missing something

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for uploading TCX files (it's basically the same as your csv file as it's also text based) into a folder in Dropbox (I'm using saver) scope

```
  static func dropboxSync() {
      let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient
      let latestTCXpath = TCXfuncs.listTCX()[0]
      let fullPathName =  "/" + latestTCXpath.lastPathComponent
      
      let fileData = try! Data(contentsOf: latestTCXpath)
      
      _ = client?.files.upload(path: fullPathName, input: fileData)
        .response { response, error in
          if let response = response {
            print(response)
          } else if let error = error {
            print(error)
          }
        }
      //        .progress { progressData in
      //          print(progressData)
    }
```

note:
These are the 2 items which I got stumped based on the official docs from SwiftyDropbox on GitHub.

fullPathName is "/" + "workout.tcx" (file gets uploaded to my dropbox within the Apps directory under the directory where I specify in App Console). Hence, the workout.tcx file would get written to

```
 -- dropbox
   -- Apps
     -- Breakaway
       -- workout.tcx
```

latestTCXpath is the full pathname to where the workout.tcx is stored within the iOS app's document directory. Example in the simulator:

```
file:///Users/testUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B4759D88-DFB6-43C0-A6E9-84FE3F23B9A0/data/Containers/Data/Application/8C348B27-FB2E-42E2-8425-92844DF18596/Documents/workout.tcx
```